# my makefile cannot compile the C program

Tags: c, compilation, ibm-mq

I have a makefile

```
EXECUTABLE = $(ONLINE_HOME)/bin/fin2ici    
OBJECTS = $(ONLINE_HOME)/src/dte_mq.o \    
      $(ONLINE_HOME)/src/fin2ici.o    


#CC = /db/pub/infra/SUNWspro/6.2/SUNWspro/bin/cc -DMQ_SEND    
CC = /usr/vacpp/bin/cc -DMQ_SEND    

ALLINCL    =    -I$(ONLINE_HOME)/inc -I$(MQM_HOME)/inc -I$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public    

MQLIB =   -L${MQM_HOME}/ -lmqmcs -lmqmzse    

MYLIB = -L${ONLINE_HOME}/src/ -lmqm    

#ORALIB = -L${ORACLE_HOME}/lib32/ -lclntsh    
ORALIB = -L${ORACLE_HOME}/lib/ -lclntsh    
ALLLIB     =     $(MQLIB) \    
             $(ORALIB) \    
             $(MYLIB) \    
            -lsocket -lnsl -ldl    


CFLAGS     =    -g \    
            $(ALLINCL)    


all: $(EXECUTABLE)    

COMPILE.c =  $(CC)  $(CFLAGS)    


.SUFFIXES:       .o    
.c.o:    
    $(COMPILE.c) -c $*.c -o ${<:.c=.o}    

$(EXECUTABLE):  $(OBJECTS) $(LIB)    
    @echo Linking $(EXECUTABLE)        
    $(CC)  $(OBJECTS) -o  $(EXECUTABLE) $(ALLLIB)        


clean:        
    /bin/rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)        

depend: $(OBJS:.o=.h) $(OBJS:.o=.cpp) makefile.fin2ici
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
$ make -f ./makefile.fin2ici
Linking /applications/dte/bin/fin2ici
    /usr/vacpp/bin/cc     -DMQ_SEND  /applications/dte/src/dte_mq.o  /applications/dte/src/fin2ici.o          -o  /applications/dte/bin/fin2ici -L/usr/mqm/ -lmqmcs -lmqmzse      -L/data/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.7/lib/ -lclntsh  -L/applications/dte/src/   -lmqm  -lsocket -lnsl -ldl       
ld: 0706-006 Cannot find or open library file: -l socket    
    ld:open(): No such file or directory    
: The error code from the last command is 255.   


Stop.
```

Could you help to find mistake?

Comment: do you have any such socket lib on your system?

Comment: I don't really know. How can I check it? The program worked on different server. Now we moved it to AIX UNIX

Comment: when I take this line off, it shows me more errors

Comment: Read this [socket tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/index.htm)

Comment: What errors do you see without `-lsocket`? You don't see 'more' errors, these errors were just hidden by the fact that the compilation process stopped when seeing that `socket` is not there.

Comment: ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .ologof
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .orlon
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oopen
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oclose
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oexec
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .ocom
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oparse
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .odefin
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .oexfet
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .obndrv
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .ofetch
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more

Comment: [This](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/CannotcreateexecutableforOpenEdgeDataServerforOracle) may help.

Comment: to avoid the macros being evaluated every time they are accessed, use `:=` rather than `=`

Comment: In Makefile contents, the <tab> has a very special meaning.  Therefore, use spaces except when wanting the special meaning of a tab character

Comment: do not have any spaces after the `\` at the end of a line, other wise it loses its' special meaning

Comment: the macro: `online_home` doesn't seem to be defined within the posted makefile contents/  Similar considerations exist for `MOM_HOME` and `ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: regarding: `CFLAGS     =    -g \`  this is a very poor way to declare the `CFLAGS` macro.   Should also enable the warnings.  perhaps by: ( for `gcc`, your compiler may be different:  `CFLAGS := -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Comment: the phony targets `all` and `clean` should be preceded by a statement similar to: `.PHONY : all clean`